# CFGetRetainCount returns 2 after creating an object, should be 1?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, retain, reference-counting, retaincount

When I do a retain count on this object it is 2. Why is this? Surely it should be one as I have just initialised it and not assigned it or anything...

```
let testC: TestClass = TestClass()
print(CFGetRetainCount(testC))
```

This was done in an empty single view xcode project...TestClass is an empty class and viewcontroller instantiates it once, retain count is 2:

[image: View Controller creates one test class]

[image: empty class]